# MySQL SELECT INNER JOIN and LIKE

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I whant to do something like this:

```
SELECT
    s.name,
    COUNT(r.request_log_id) AS NumberOfRequests
FROM
    station AS s
LEFT JOIN request_log AS r ON r.requested LIKE '%s.station_id%'
GROUP BY 1
```

But this gives 0 in the NumberOfRequests and i think it is becouse its hardcoded s.station_id its running LIKE on.

Does anyone know how i can do this?

For your information, r.requested is a string whit some data in it and one example is

> /StationInfo - stationID = "262" - Status = 0

So it is the staitonid i whant to get LIKE on and cound how many rows in request_log table it is in that have the station id for the first table named station

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First approach:

```
SELECT
    s.name,
    COUNT(r.request_log_id) AS NumberOfRequests
FROM
    station AS s
LEFT JOIN request_log AS r 
   ON r.requested LIKE concat( '%',s.station_id, '%')
GROUP BY 1
```

be careful with this non equijoin.

see you.